# PhalconPHP vs Slim

Tags: php, performance, doctrine-orm, phalcon, slim

I'm currently planning to develop a REST API for my applications, and I've been looking a lot at existing PHP frameworks, but also existing solutions to speed up PHP execution.

My goal here is to get the best performance, but also without compromising development speed.

I've been hesitating between two:

- PhalconPHP (using only the Micro application)
- Slim + Doctrine2 ORM

I read some articles about PhalconPHP and it seems really fast as it's written in C as a PHP extension. But I do prefer Doctrine2's ORM.

Also, Slim is by itself really fast, and I took a look also on HHVM by Facebook, in order to speed up PHP execution.

What I'm wondering:

1. If I do use Doctrine2 ORM in place of Phalcon's native ORM, will Doctrine2 slow down the application, as it's not written in C like Phalcon's one ?
2. Is Phalcon's native ORM worth it ?
3. If I use Slim, will I miss some important features that could slow down the development process ? I do understand it's a micro-framework, and that's what I want: use multiple smalls components in order to build my application stack, but will I miss out some great features available in PhalconPHP ?
4. PhalconPHP vs Slim personnal opinion ? In order of development speed, but also scalability/performance

Also, I saw this issue: [Phalcon's ORM is slow](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/6303/low-performance-of-orm). Don't know what you think about this?

Comment: The speed of frameworks is generally an overrated characteristic, and often incorrectly measured in real-world terms anyway. Use what you find productive. I personally don't think frameworks should get involved writing their own ORMs, but of the full-stack frameworks, I think Symfony is the only one not to reinvent the wheel. (Of course Slim etc don't, but they're microframeworks - they _definitely_ should not get involved in writing an ORM).

Comment: (Aside: we get these "what is the best framework" questions every week, and they are - fortunately or otherwise, depending on your view - off topic. You will probably get a few pointers in the comments).

Comment: I know there is a lot of theses "Best framework" questions, that's why I tried to be as specific as possible in my questions ;) Thanks for the reply on overall performance and ORM.

Comment: Still off-topic though, since it is almost entirely opinion based. Some people will like one, and others with like the second. I really like Slim with Propel + Plates, so count up a vote for that! I've not tried Phalcon.

Answer (score 2):

1.- Of course, anything beyond native phalcon will be handled as php code and so you will not take advantage of it.

2.- For most cases yes. Not because of database transactions but because everything around the application.Most of the needs can be done by using phalcon ORM or simple query language.

3.- You bet. That's the best of phalcon, you have a complete environment like any other framework but with the needs of less than the simplest framework. Only you know if you will miss something because it depends on your needs.

4.- Once you get use of it, it is really worth :)